# In UILocalNotification how to add system sound file for sound property not custom sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Custom file we can add to `localNotification` but my requirement is from `System/Library/Audio/UISounds/New/` path sound file. Need to play as per user selection

Answer (score -2):

**It is very simple:**

i have edited my code:

Just add the path as `NSURL` and then add that url to `AVAudioPlayer`. Call `play` method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/ma.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSError *error;
 audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

 [audioPlayer play];


}
```

Add default sound for uilocalnotification

```
- (void)scheduleNotification {

  [reminderText resignFirstResponder];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

  Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
  if (cls != nil) {

    UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
    notif.fireDate = [datePicker date];
    notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    notif.alertBody = @"Did you forget something?";
    notif.alertAction = @"Show me";

    notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:reminderText.text 
                              forKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
    notif.userInfo = userDict;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
    [notif release];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,My question is in Local notification Instead of default sound how we can play the system sound. notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName; Here i need to give the system sound path.so when my app in background that system sound should play instead of default one

Comment: Please understand my question,I know how to play the sound file.In local notification How you will add system sound file path to play in Background not in foreground